# Using replace method in python 3.6

Tags: python, replace, python-3.6

I need to replace "`!@#$%^&*()\n{}[]()_-+=<>?\xa0;'/.,`" with a blank. I am using replace method but it seems it is deprecated on python 3.6. `word_list = []` is a list which will have all the words extracted from the webpage. Then `clean_up_list` method will clean the symbols and replace them with blank space.
I used  `for`  to loop through the length of symbols and replace symbols with blank. I used
`word  = word.replace(symbols[i],"")` ; Any help on how to use  the replace method so that symbols are replaced and words are printed without symbols between them.

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

My Code:

```
url = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.servicenow.com/solutions-by-category.html").read()
word_list = []
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(url,'lxml')
word_list.append([element.get_text() for element in soup.select('a')])
print(word_list)

def clean_up_list(word_list):
    clean_word_list = []
    for word in word_list:
        symbols = "!@#$%^&*()\n{}[]()_-+=<>?\xa0;'/.,"
        for i in range(0,len(symbols)):

            word  = word.replace(symbols[i],"")
            #print(type(word))

                #print(type(word))
                #word.replace(symbols[i]," ")
        if(len(word) > 0):
            #print(word)
            clean_word_list.append(word)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to strip punctuation from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: `replace` is not depreciated, it is a string method, not for lists. See the suggested dupe for how to perform a string replacement

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors here: first you do *not* construct a list of strings, but a list of lists of strings. This line:

```
word_list.append([element.get_text() for element in soup.select('a')])
```

should be:

```
word_list.extend([element.get_text() for element in soup.select('a')])
```

Furthermore you cannot call `replace` **on the list directly** (it is not a method of a `list` object). You need to this for every entry.

Next you also specify (correctly) than you then have to call `replace(..)` for every character in the `symbols` string. Which is of course inefficient. You can however use `translate(..)` for that.

So you can replace the **entire `for` loop with with *list comprehension***:

```
symbols = "!@#$%^&*()\n{}[]()_-+=<>?\xa0;'/.,"
clean_word_list = [word.translate(None,symbols) for word in word_list]
```

Comment: It still won't clean up the symbols. Need to check with regular expression.

Comment: @Shishir13: please provide a sample `word_list`.

Answer (score -1):

Try explicitly converting the word to a string, as the error code you're receiving mentions the object is a 'list' not string and that the replace method cannot be called on lists. For example (notice the second to last line):

```
def clean_up_list(word_list):
clean_word_list = []
for word in word_list:
    word = str(word)
    symbols = "!@#$%^&*()\n{}[]()_-+=<>?\xa0;'/.,"
```